# Select one best model according to accuracy, precision, recall, f1 score and roc score

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, model-evaluations

I have two classifiers that classify the same dataset with these results:

```
 Model        | Accuracy| Precision| Recall | F1 Score| ROC Score
--------------| --------| ---------|--------|---------|---------
 Random Forest| 90%     | 0.61     | 0.7    | 0.64    | 0.81      
 XGBoost      | 91%     | 0.70     | 0.67   | 0.66    | 0.80
```

I am not sure but It seems to me XGBoost is the best model since it has 91% accuracy and higher precision and F1 score than Random Forest. **Can anyone please help me to choose the best model from the above result?**

Comment: Is it a binary classification or a multi class classification?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. they are close, the difference might not be significant. If you have a reason to favour recall pick the random forest one, otherwise XGBoost is slightly better. The ROC score is not relevant here.

Comment: @spectre its binary classification

Comment: @Erwan thanks :)

Comment: What people are saying here is what metric is most important to the problem you are solving. Maybe none of these metrics are the most important. In most of my modeling problems, these are not the most important metrics. Think about the problem you are solving and find the appropriate metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment suggests, XGBoost is a better model. It's F1 score (which is nothing but a combination of precision and recall) is slightly better than RandomForest.
Depending on your use case, if Recall is more important, than go for RandomForest.